# viewDidAppear() running on every click

Tags: swift, viewdidappear

I am trying to create an animation slide in for two textfields and a label.  However for some reason the viewDidAppear() function runs every time you attempt to click the textfield, causing them to continue to animate.  Does anyone have any ideas?

This is my code for the function:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    //Some Code here
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 0.5,
                               usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3,
                               initialSpringVelocity: 0.5,
                               options: [], animations: {
                                self.Email.center.x += 475
                                self.Password.center.x -= 400
        }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 2.0,
                               options: [],
                               animations: {
                                self.LoginButton.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: nil)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 0.5,
                               usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3,
                               initialSpringVelocity: 0.5,
                               options: [], animations: {
                                self.LoginL.center.y += 100
        }, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Try adding call to super.viewDidAppear(animated).

Comment: Adding the super call fixed it, thank you!

Comment: Glad that it helped, accept the answer and close the ticket please. 
P.S. you might want to chec the new [UIViewPropertyAnimator API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator) as it's designed for cases like yours - messing around with alpha and frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we found out the problem was with the UIViewController's life cycle - it was needed to call `super.viewDidAppear(animated)`.

Answer (score -1):

try to run it viewWillAppear instead, your animation will be run only when your screen loads for the first time.